# Benchmarking and finding bottlenecks with Tensorflow

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, benchmarking, intel, nvidia

I am looking for tools that could assist me in creating a data flow timeline for training and evaluating CNN models.

I would like to know how long each hardware component takes to do its job with the hope of finding a bottleneck. For example, how long does it take to:

- do CPU preprocessing (such as loading and batching data)
- pass the data along PCIe to the GPU
- use the batch to get the gradient descent
- pass the data back along PCIe to the CPU
- average the gradient descent results from multiple GPUs (if relevant)
- do remaining processing on CPU

I'm doing this research on the [CIFAR10 CNN from the Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) with the intention of porting the findings over to a more complex CNN. I'm working with:

- GPU: 2x NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti
- CPU: Intel i7-6850K
- RAM: 64GB
- OS:  Ubuntu 16.04